# How to get the raw xml data sent to the web service

Tags: xml, web-services

I am calling a web service using the following:

```
ServiceReference1.TestClient svc = new ServiceReference1.TestClient("TestBinding");


svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User1";
svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Pwd1";
ServiceReference1.GenerateIDRequest rq = new ServiceReference1.GenerateIDRequest();


var response = svc.GenerateID(rq);
```

What I want to do is get raw xml of the request sent to the web service, including the header.

I added the folowing section to my App.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="trace.log"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

and now I get `trace.log` file generated in my bin folder. The only problem, is that request xml there is in the following format:

```
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000000 : 3C 73 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C-6F 70 65 20 78 6D 6C 6E : <s:Envelope xmln
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000010 : 73 3A 73 3D 22 68 74 74-70 3A 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 : s:s="http://sche
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000020 : 6D 61 73 2E 78 6D 6C 73-6F 61 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F : mas.xmlsoap.org/
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000030 : 73 6F 61 70 2F 65 6E 76-65 6C 6F 70 65 2F 22 3E : soap/envelope/">
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000040 : 3C 73 3A 42 6F 64 79 20-78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 78 73 : <s:Body xmlns:xs
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000050 : 69 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A-2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 77 33 : i="http://www.w3
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000060 : 2E 6F 72 67 2F 32 30 30-31 2F 58 4D 4C 53 63 68 : .org/2001/XMLSch
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000070 : 65 6D 61 2D 69 6E 73 74-61 6E 63 65 22 20 78 6D : ema-instance" xm
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000080 : 6C 6E 73 3A 78 73 64 3D-22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F : lns:xsd="http://
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 00000090 : 77 77 77 2E 77 33 2E 6F-72 67 2F 32 30 30 31 2F : www.w3.org/2001/
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [14476] 000000A0 : 58 4D 4C 53 63 68 65 6D-61 22 3E 3C 43 72 65 61 : XMLSchema">
```

How do I get pure raw xml without having to edit through `trace.log` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this (inside `<system.serviceModel>`):

```
<diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="300" />
    <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
        messageFlowTracing="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

and this (after `<system.serviceModel>`):

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="c:\temp\messages.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add initializeData="c:\temp\tracelog.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

You can set the level of tracing you want in `switchValue`

You can inspect raw message using *Microsoft Service Trace Viewer*.

Comment: that did not do anything at all

Comment: When you consume the service, wasn't created any log?

Comment: there was only an old log that has been created before I changed my config file per your suggestion

Comment: there's something strange... I've tested now, with the same lines in the configuration file, and the file was generated when I've consumed the service using wcf test client

Comment: could you post the relevant part of your service configuration file?